# Book featuring magic headgear and death by cats

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I read a novel, at most ten years ago, that featured a villain of some sort (not the big bad- more of a side quest) who wore a stack of hats.  As in, probably upward of one dozen hats on his head simultaneously.  I'm pretty sure there were talking cats involved, and that the man's headgear may have protected him from them.

I think our hero (maybe a teenage girl?) came upon the cats first, and the bad guy "saved" her from them, but they were really trying to warn her to stay away from him or his house.  Eventually, our hero figures everything out and may actually lead the bad guy to his death by cats.

I'm fairly certain that this was a book aimed at young adults, probably in a fantasy setting of some sort, but I can't tell you much more.  Can anybody help me out?

Comment: My Google-Fu is not strong today. I only end up with Dr Seuss.

Comment: "Looking for a book featuring magic headgear and death by cats" Aren't we all? I wonder if this villain was actually [Johnny Two-Hats](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8K1fTZaR7w), a few years down the road.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's *[Abarat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abarat)*, by Clive Barker. Candy defeats Wolfswinkel (the man with the hats) by knocking the hats off, and escapes with Malingo (Wolfswinkel's slave). When they get outside they're introduced to the tarrie-cats who were the gaolers.